# How to add text with different weights to a single ListItem using iText List

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I have created a list of questions and answers with iText 7 where the question and answer are both shown in the same line of the list. I am trying to make the questions bold while leaving the answers with the normal font weight. When I run code similar to what is shown below I get this (com.itextpdf.layout.element.Text@73df99a1) in place of the bold text. Is it possible to get fonts of various weights in the same iText 7 ListItem?

```
String dest = "destination.pdf"
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdf);

List qaList = new List();

qaList.add(new ListItem(new Text("Question 1?").setBold() + "Answer 1"));
qaList.add(new ListItem(new Text("Question 2?").setBold() + "Answer 2"));

document.add(qaList);

document.close();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can apply different styles in an iText 7 `ListItem` by explicitly creating a `Paragraph` containing pieces with different styles and adding that paragraph to a list item:

```
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument))
List qaList = new List();

ListItem item = new ListItem();
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.add(new Text("Question 1? ").setBold())
         .add(new Text("Answer 1"))
         .setMarginTop(0).setMarginBottom(0);
item.add(paragraph);
qaList.add(item);
item = new ListItem();
paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.add(new Text("Question 2? ").setBold())
         .add(new Text("Answer 2"))
         .setMarginTop(0).setMarginBottom(0);
item.add(paragraph);
qaList.add(item);

document.add(qaList);
```

*([StyledListItems](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/StyledListItems.java#L38) test `testAddMultiStyledListItems`)*

results in

[image: screen shot]

---

As an aside, the reason why you

> get this (com.itextpdf.layout.element.Text@73df99a1) in place of the bold text

is that in

```
qaList.add(new ListItem(new Text("Question 1?").setBold() + "Answer 1"));
```

you actually execute a `String` concatenation,

```
new Text("Question 1?").setBold() + "Answer 1"
```

calls `toString()` of the resulting object of `new Text("Question 1?").setBold()` and to this String adds `"Answer 1"`.

Comment: Yes this works. I had actually tried essentially the same thing but it didn't work `testList.add(new ListItem().add(new Paragraph().add(new Text("Bold").setBold()).add(" not Bold")));`

Comment: When I'm testing something, I try not to use the fluid notation too much; it looks compact but it's more difficult to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem functionality in iText 7 to allow the use of multiple fonts within a ListItem. I resolved my problem by abandoning the list and instead using a paragraph for each list item.

```
String dest = "destination.pdf"
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdf);

Paragraph qaItem1 = new Paragraph().add(new Text("Question 1?").setBold()).add("Answer 1"));
Paragraph qaItem1 = new Paragraph().add(new Text("Question 1?").setBold()).add("Answer 1"));

document.add(qaItem1);
document.add(qaItem2);

document.close();
```